Why did std::sort use this simple strict weak ordering compare still crash?
Here is my code:
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void test()
{
    vector<vector<int>> info = {{0,0,999}, {0,1,1000}, {0,2,1001},
                {0,3,1002}, {0,4,1003}, {0,5,1004},
                {0,6,1005}, {0,7,1006}, {1,0,1000},
                {1,1,999}, {1,2,1000}, {1,3,1001},
                {1,4,1002}, {1,5,1003}, {1,6,1004},
                {1,7,1005}, {2,0,1001}, {2,1,1000},
                {2,2,999}, {2,3,1000}, {2,4,1001},
                {2,5,1002}, {2,6,1003}, {2,7,1004},
                {3,0,1002}, {3,1,1001}, {3,2,1000},
                {3,3,999}, {3,4,1000}, {3,5,1001},
                {3,6,1002}, {3,7,1003}, {4,0,1003},
                {4,1,1002}, {4,2,1001}, {4,3,1000},
                {4,4,999}, {4,5,1000}, {4,6,1001},
                {4,7,1002}, {5,0,1004}, {5,1,1003},
                {5,2,1002}, {5,3,1001}, {5,4,1000},
                {5,5,999}, {5,6,1000}, {5,7,1001},
                {6,0,1005}, {6,1,1004}, {6,2,1003},
                {6,3,1002}, {6,4,1001}, {6,5,1000},
                {6,6,999}, {6,7,1000}, {7,0,1006},
                {7,1,1005}, {7,2,1004}, {7,3,1003},
                {7,4,1002},{7,5,1001}};  
    auto cmp=[](const auto& a,const auto& b){
      if(a[2]<b[2])return true;
      if(a[0]<b[0])return true;
      return a[1]<b[1];       
 };

 sort(begin(info),end(info),cmp);

}
int main()
{
  test();
}

I use g++ 13.2 compile under Ubuntu 24.04 LTS(Linux 6.8.0-39-generic) build and run the code crashes on sort, very strange:
zzhao@zzhao-System-Version:~$ g++  -std=c++20 z3.cpp

zzhao@zzhao-System-Version:~$ ./a.out

Segmentation fault (core dumped)


FWIW, the new and safe way to do this is return std::tie(var1, var2, ..., varN) <operator> std::tie(other_var1, other_var2, ..., other_varN)

Automatic checks for strict weak ordering and How to define operator< on an n-tuple that satisfies a strict weak ordering

@user12002570 I think the OP is aware of the requirement for the comparator (see the title). The question is how exactly it is violated in this case (and the dupes do not help to identify the specific issue). I explained it in my answer.

Your comparison does not define a strict weak ordering. Given the failure I'm not sure what gave you the confidence that it does.

@wohlstad Yes, I know. That is exactly why I added this dupe which explains this in much more details. If OP were to really understand the concept of weak strict ordering they should've figured it out by themselves. OP is aware of the term "strict weak ordering" but don't actually understand it which is why I added the dupe

@user12002570 it's still not addressing the specirfic problem in the OP's code (due to the ifs they implemented). But I won't fight you...

@wohlstad The answer in the dupe is applicable to every possible case that violates strict weak ordering including this specific problem. To be a dupe, the answer should just solve OP's problem. It is not necessary that the dupe must be exactly the same as the new question. I mean people can create new questions having different examples showing violation of strict weak ordering, but that doesn't make them new question. They will still be answered by the mentioned answer because it explains all the conditions.

@user12002570 OK I accept.

@wohlstad Glad we agreed here.

Your comparator does not respect strict-weak ordering.
Take for example:
a = {2,0,1},  b = {1,0,2}
It will return true for a<b (due to the first if in the comparator), but also true for b<a (due to the second if in it).
Since this does not satisfy the requirement of a comparator for std::sort, it causes undefined behavior.

thank u very mush! Maybe std::sort should add some validation check for comparator !

I don't think a check is present. it's basically undefined-behavior (although MSVC in debug triggered an assert).

The code is crashing because the comparison function for sorting is messed up. Basically, it isn't following the rules that std::sort needs to work properly. The original function is all over the place, sometimes saying one thing is smaller, sometimes not - it is super inconsistent.
To fix it, I had to rewrite the comparison part. Now it checks the third number first, then the first, then the second. It's way more logical and consistent this way.
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

void test() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> info = {{0,0,999}, {0,1,1000}, {0,2,1001},
                {0,3,1002}, {0,4,1003}, {0,5,1004},
                {0,6,1005}, {0,7,1006}, {1,0,1000},
                {1,1,999}, {1,2,1000}, {1,3,1001},
                {1,4,1002}, {1,5,1003}, {1,6,1004},
                {1,7,1005}, {2,0,1001}, {2,1,1000},
                {2,2,999}, {2,3,1000}, {2,4,1001},
                {2,5,1002}, {2,6,1003}, {2,7,1004},
                {3,0,1002}, {3,1,1001}, {3,2,1000},
                {3,3,999}, {3,4,1000}, {3,5,1001},
                {3,6,1002}, {3,7,1003}, {4,0,1003},
                {4,1,1002}, {4,2,1001}, {4,3,1000},
                {4,4,999}, {4,5,1000}, {4,6,1001},
                {4,7,1002}, {5,0,1004}, {5,1,1003},
                {5,2,1002}, {5,3,1001}, {5,4,1000},
                {5,5,999}, {5,6,1000}, {5,7,1001},
                {6,0,1005}, {6,1,1004}, {6,2,1003},
                {6,3,1002}, {6,4,1001}, {6,5,1000},
                {6,6,999}, {6,7,1000}, {7,0,1006},
                {7,1,1005}, {7,2,1004}, {7,3,1003},
                {7,4,1002},{7,5,1001}};  

    auto cmp = [](const auto& a, const auto& b) {
        if (a[2] != b[2]) return a[2] < b[2];
        if (a[0] != b[0]) return a[0] < b[0];
        return a[1] < b[1];
    };

    std::sort(begin(info), end(info), cmp);

    for (const auto& v : info) {
        std::cout << v[0] << " " << v[1] << " " << v[2] << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    test();
    return 0;
}

